# Why does parsing a date with weekyear return the wrong year?

Tags: java, jodatime

```
DateTime time=DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-ww").parseDateTime("2013-01");
```

where `DateTimeFormat` is `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`.

When I execute the above, time becomes `2013-12-30T00:00:00.000`
what am I doing wrong? Is this a bug? I expect it to be the first week of 2013, not the last.

Comment: What value do you expect instead? Why?

Comment: The date of the first week of 2013

Comment: 2013-02 gives 2013-01-07 so I would expect 2012-12-31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/226).

The `w`, week of weekyear, pattern letter is meant to be used with `x`, weekyear. From the [javadoc of `DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
 x       weekyear                     year          1996
 w       week of weekyear             number        27
```

Change your pattern to

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("xxxx-ww")
```

and you'll parse to

```
2012-12-31T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

Depending on your `Locale`, the first week of 2013 started in 2012.